# How to search a large number of files(suppose 100,000 files) which are spread across multiple servers in Hadoop?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hadoop2

Sample Apple Interview Question:

Suppose you have 100,000 files spread across multiple servers and you wanted to process all of them? How would you do that in Hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

First put all the files in to Hdfs/(may be s3)/hive by gathering them via sftp of ftp etc....

then you have unified storage hdfs. you can apply mapreduce or spark etc to process them based on your requirements.

No one can do anything if they have wide variety of data sources / servers instead of gathering them ( called data ingestion ) followed by data processing using any available frameworks.